# Module not found: Can't resolve '../Utilities/Platform'

Tags: javascript, react-native

After adding react-native-video I am getting this error.
I checked the repo and I see that no such a file called Platform.js exists, but there are Platform.android.js and Platform.android.js.
Does anyone know the expected behavior for loading this file, and how it's supposed work for web

```js
  23 | const PixelRatio = require('react-native/Libraries/Utilities/PixelRatio');
  24 | 
> 25 | const Platform = require('../Utilities/Platform');
     |                 ^
  26 | const invariant = require('invariant');
  27 | 
  28 | const {
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you're using expo, try the built-in https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/video/